# grabAttributeFrom() method not returning the attribute value

Tags: testing, attributes, automated-tests, testcafe, codeceptjs

I am trying to get the attribute value of an element by using `I.grabAttributeFrom()` method but I always get undefined instead of the attribute value. My code is

```
Scenario('Smoketest', async (I) => {

const columnIndex = await I.grabAttributeFrom('//th[text()="Status"]', 'aria-colindex');

});
```

The element is like that

```html
<th aria-colindex = "2">
"Status"
<span> ... </span>
</th>
```

And I am using testcafe in codeceptjs.

Comment: I changed your selector to `th`, and it still does not work. I debugged the `testcafe` module, and it works as expected: the value `2` is returned. Probably the issue lies somewhere on the `codeceptjs` side. It makes sense to report it in their github repo.

Comment: Thank you for confirming me that it is not a testcafe issue. I will check codeceptjs github repo.

Comment: Fix was merged. Now waiting for next (2.4.0) release.

Thanks for bug found

Comment: Welcome. I will check the next release :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to get it to work either, so I wrote a protractor helper that worked for me to grab text attributes:

```
  /**
   * Function to return the text content of all elements matching with the locator in an array
   * @param xpath object
   */
  async getElementsText(locator) {
    const driver = this.helpers.Protractor.browser;
    await driver.waitForAngular();
    // await console.log("Getting text for: " + locator.xpath);
    return driver.element.all(by.xpath(locator.xpath)).getAttribute("textContent");
  }
```